# Function is not working when the its pressed or clicked

Tags: javascript

On this below code, when i try to add new para, it working, but, when i try to delete the added paras, the `remove button` got removed instead of removing paragraphs. what is the prob over here? please

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Iteration Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Sb1" style="border:1pt solid">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function add(){
                var Element=document.createElement("p");
                Element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is the sample Text"));
                document.getElementById("Sb1").appendChild(Element);
            }
            function remove(){
                alert("EYYS");
                document.getElementById("Sb1").style.border="1pt solid red";
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="add()">Add</button> <button onclick="remove()">Remove</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just try a different name for `remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you calling native remove function instead of yours please see that [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/zubakavo/1/edit)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Iteration Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="Sb1" style="border:1pt solid">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function add(){
var Element=document.createElement("p");
Element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is the sample Text"));
document.getElementById("Sb1").appendChild(Element);
}
function _remove(){
alert("EYYS");
document.getElementById("Sb1").style.border="1pt solid red";
}
</script>
<button onclick="add()">Add</button> 
  <button onclick="_remove()">Remove</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

Rename your function name **remove** to any other for **removeitem** it will work

Answer (score 0):

`remove()` is reserved function() for javascript operation, you can rename it with a new function name like following

```
function removeItem(){
  alert("EYYS");
  document.getElementById("Sb1").style.border="1pt solid red";
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/judeluta/1/)